# Mouse scroll direction changes function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a web page which has some interesting functionality.

Simplified, the page has a div which covers almost full screen (top and left edges show the background). Inside that div is a scrollable text area.

I need to implement functionality where mouse wheel down moves the almost-full-screen-div down until it goes out of sight. Then mouse scroll up moves it back up until it is in the original position after which mouse scroll up is supposed to scroll the text area down. And vice versa, crolling up from initial position scrolls the text area down. All this regardless of the cursor position.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem so any suggestions and tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I belive what you are asking is this;

**[Live Demo](https://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=6d9582c01744c6a767997745d8bf13d5)**

Referance: [Capture Scroll on Overflow:Hidden elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478298/capture-scroll-on-overflowhidden-elements)